# Why do I have "Object reference not set to an instance" in new project page

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I just updated my Visual Studio from Silverlight 3 to Silverlight 4 and started having this unusual error message.

[image]

No matter how many project I created it's the same. Restarted Visual Studio and my machine, still the same thing

Update: I have copied the stack trace from the image

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightMetadataContext.SilverlightXamlExtensionImplementations.<GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings>d__8.MoveNext()
   at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
   at MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
   at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent, PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider)
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.FullParse(Boolean convertToXamlWithErrors)
   at MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootItem()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.ModifiableDocumentTree.get_ModifiableRootItem()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupDocumentManagerBase.get_LoadState()
   at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
   at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
   at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
```

Comment: sometimes you can resolve these by googling the top line or two of the stack trace or some substring of the stack trace. You'll probably want to at least paste that stack trace as text in the question.

Comment: @MatthewMartin that's a new project and have not written any code. It's just the default generated project setup. The Stack trace is already in the image - design mode, not runtime

Comment: Poss dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015170/system-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje

Comment: Its common problem with VS for mismatch of runtime environment for different silverlight version. `designer view will not work in such cases` its installation issue

Comment: @LukeHutton based on that link, I have uninstalled the Silverlight 5 and re-install silverlight 4, it's now asking to install Silverlight runtime again... which caused the issue in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by installing the Silverlight 4 runtime. Whenever you click on the suggested prerequisite update link in Visual Studio, the latest version is installed, which is currently Silverlight 5 runtime which was not what I wanted. It would be fine if we could be given option to choose which to install instead of installing a latest version that breaks stuffs.

I uninstalled Silverlight 5 runtime and used these links to resintall version 4

Here are the links I used:

- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18149
- http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18149

Suggested by this answer

- [Where can I get the "Silverlight Developer Runtime" for Silverlight 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232271/where-can-i-get-the-silverlight-developer-runtime-for-silverlight-4)

Answer (score 0):

This Error Raise when You Reference Of Old Version So You Should Add New Reference For You Updated Version

Comment: shouldn't visual studio pick the right references when creating new project?

Comment: Also You Should Try To Remove All Reference of Old Version And Add New Reference of Sl5

Comment: Yes You Should Create New Project So It's Automatically Prefer New Reference I Think So